# min value till row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some problem where data is sorted by date, for example something like this:

```
date,       value,      min
2015-08-17,    3,        nan
2015-08-18,    2,        nan
2015-08-19,    4,        nan
2015-08-28,    1,        nan
2015-08-29,    5,        nan
```

Now I want to save `min` values in `min` column till this row, so result would look something like this:

```
date,       value,      min
2015-08-17,    3,        3
2015-08-18,    2,        2
2015-08-19,    4,        2
2015-08-28,    1,        1
2015-08-29,    5,        1
```

I've tried some options, but still don't get what I'm doing wrong, here is one example that I tried:

```
data['min'] = min(data['value'], data['min'].shift())
```

I don't want to iterate through all rows because the data I have is big. What is the best strategy you can write using pandas for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are working with big dataset, with focus on performance, here's one using NumPy's [`np.minimum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) -

```
df['min'] = np.minimum.accumulate(df.value)
```

Sample run -

```
In [70]: df
Out[70]: 
         date  value  min
0  2015-08-17      3  NaN
1  2015-08-18      2  NaN
2  2015-08-19      4  NaN
3  2015-08-28      1  NaN
4  2015-08-29      5  NaN

In [71]: df['min'] = np.minimum.accumulate(df.value)

In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
         date  value  min
0  2015-08-17      3    3
1  2015-08-18      2    2
2  2015-08-19      4    2
3  2015-08-28      1    1
4  2015-08-29      5    1
```

Runtime test -

```
In [65]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(1000000)), columns=list(['value']))

# @MaxU's soln using pandas cummin
In [66]: %timeit df['min'] = df.value.cummin()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.84 ms per loop

In [67]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(1000000)), columns=list(['value']))

# Using NumPy
In [68]: %timeit df['min'] = np.minimum.accumulate(df.value)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.97 ms per loop
```

Comment: your solution is faster as always ;-)

Comment: @jezrael I think with NaNs, it will give everything after the first NaN as `NaNs`.

Comment: @jezrael Just to add to the previous comment, since the `value` column doesn't have any `NaN`, I think we are okay here.

Comment: @jezrael We could use a mask and set those NaNs as something greater than global max to effectively ignore those, then use `accumulate` and finally put back those `NaNs`. All these only if we need to handle NaNs in `value` column. So, I guess its a note to OP too, if such a case arises.

Answer (score 5):

Use [cummin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummin.html) method:

```
In [53]: df['min'] = df.value.cummin()

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
         date  value  min
0  2015-08-17      3    3
1  2015-08-18      2    2
2  2015-08-19      4    2
3  2015-08-28      1    1
4  2015-08-29      5    1
```